# Codeigniter 3 DBFORGE, #1064 -You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3, dbforge

I can't figure out what's the problem in the sql query. I'm using the dbforge library in codeigniter 3.
**Mysql Version: 8.0**

```
<?php

class Migration_merchant_withdraw_request extends CI_Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        $this->dbforge->add_field('id');
        $this->dbforge->add_field([
            '`mitra_id` VARCHAR NOT NULL',
            '`amount` INT NOT NULL',
            '`password` VARCHAR NOT NULL',
            '`status` INT DEFAULT 0',
            '`created_at` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
            '`updated_at` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
        ]);
        $this->dbforge->create_table('merchant_withdraw_request');
    }

    public function down()
    {
        $this->dbforge->drop_table('merchant_withdraw_request');
    }
}
```

Which generates the sql query.

```
CREATE TABLE `merchant_withdraw_request` (
  `id` INT(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mitra_id` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  `amount` INT NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  `status` INT DEFAULT 0,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  CONSTRAINT `pk_merchant_withdraw_request` PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci
```

Yet, I get an error message.

> Error Number: 1064
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL, `amount` INT NOT NULL, `password` VARCHAR NOT NULL, `status` INT DE' at line 3

I tried this style of adding fields in dbforge.

```
<?php

class Migration_merchant_withdraw_request extends CI_Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        $this->dbforge->add_field('id');
        $this->dbforge->add_field([
            'mitra_id' => [
                'type' => 'VARCHAR',
            ],
            'amount' => [
                'type' => 'INT',
            ],
            'password' => [
                'type' => 'VARCHAR',
            ],
            'status' => [
                'type' => 'INT',
                'default' => 0,
            ],
            'created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
            'updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
        ]);
        $this->dbforge->create_table('merchant_withdraw_request');
    }

    public function down()
    {
        $this->dbforge->drop_table('merchant_withdraw_request');
    }
}
```

Yet it produces the same error, what's the problem?

**Problem Solved**
It turns out that, I have not set the length of the VARCHAR data type. To do this in dbforge, this would be the syntax.

```
'column_name' => [
    'type' => 'VARCHAR',
    'constraint' => 64 // Set your wanted length.
]
```

Comment: You need to declare the length of varchar data type, like varchar(10) or varchar(25) ...etc

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html

Comment: @ErgestBasha , thanks! so that's what I was missing.

Comment: Yes https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0c4e6b66083672b6dc55fc02107a7f0e

Comment: Please don't add unrelated tags. From the errors, SQL, and your statement *"Mysql Version: 8.0"* this is clearly not about SQL Server.

Comment: @ShiniDev post an answer if you solved the problem and explain what went wrong